# A really simple WebSocket server

Tags: php, html, websocket, phpwebsocket

Does anyone know of a simple WebSocket server that supports both 75 and 76 at the same time?

I used to be using phpwebsocket (I have a little php experience), until Chrome updated itself and mucked everything up.

All I really need is a server that echos messages sent to it to all other connections. Preferably written in php, but it really doesn't matter, except that I can't use a node.js solution.

Comment: If you don't want to have to worry about the realtime infrastructure you are using then you might want to investigate [hosted realtime web solutions](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#hosted-services). They take the pain away from working with a technology that, although very stable now, can still change - WebSockets, maintaining and updating any solution and also help you deal with scaling to meet demand.

Comment: Personally I find creating a custom one works best, because you can expand it to your own wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want PHP and support for WebSockets Hixie 75/76 then [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/)

However, let me suggest that you really want Hixie 75/76 support and also HyBi (07, 08, 13) support. Chrome 14 and on only support HyBi. Same is true for Firefox 6. The downloadable WebSocket prototype from Microsoft for Internet Explorer also only support HyBi.

phpwebsocket hasn't been updated since Nov 2010 and does not have any HyBi support. A couple of alternatives that support Hixe and HyBi protocols:

- python: pywebsocket(http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/)
- C: http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/
- c#: http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

There is also PHP code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087522/php-websocket-server-hybi10) which could probably be used to add HyBi support to phpwebsocket.

Also, you didn't say why node.js is not an option. If it were an option then [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) would probably be your fastest route to a working solution since it provides a client side Javascript library (in addition to the server), it has session management examples/recipes, and it has automatic fallback to long-polling for browsers that do not support WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/

Does require Python experience

Answer (score 0):

Pywebsocket has dropped their hixie support.

Use

```
--allow-draft75
```

to have compatibility with older browsers.