# websocket binary frame example

Tags: binary, websocket, frame

In Internet, I could not found any example for "websocket binary frame" communication using Javascript (as web client) and Java (as web server).

Can you anybody post few example for "websocket binary frame" communication ?

Comment: I once posted some pseudocode about binary framing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040078/not-sure-how-to-frame-data-in-websockets-draft-08/7045885#7045885.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty has supported binary frames in WebSockets since at least version 7.5.2. Here is a Jetty example that includes binary frames: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-api-send-message.html

From the server point of view, there is very little difference between sending and receiving binary data, it's just a single opcode change. When sending text, you are limited to UTF-8 encoded data. With binary you don't have that limit.

From the browser point of view, if the browser supports binary data (which really only very recent builds of Chrome support) then sending binary data involves sending an arraybuffer or blob using the `send()` method on the WebSocket object. Receiving binary data happens automatically if the server sends a binary frame. However, you can select between receiving blobs or arraybuffers by setting the `binaryType` property on your WebSocket object instance.

Comment: @stackerflow Autobahn apparently no makes reports for third party servers. I've replace the link with one to a Jetty example with binary frames.

Answer (score 1):

[Kaazing WebSocket Gateway](http://kaazing.com) has had binary support for quite a while now. Moreover it also works in older browsers that don't support WebSocket natively. And there is support for clients other than JavaScript. So you can do binary over WebSocket using JavaScript, Flash/Flex, Silverlight, .Net, or Java. You can use any browser, the fallback emulation will work in older browsers.

The backend server can be Java or anything that listens on a TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

I just know how to unwrap the content sent from browser, here is my code:

```js
socket.ondata = function(src,start,end) {
    src = src.slice(start,end);
    var maskKeys = [src[2],src[3],src[4],src[5]];
    var dest = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<src.length-6;i++){
        var mKey = maskKeys[i%4];
        dest[i] = mKey ^ src[6+i];
    }
    console.log(new Buffer(dest).toString());
}
```

Found from here: http://songpengfei.iteye.com/blog/1178310

Link there is a zipped c source code, I change it to node. And now I'm study how to send data to the client.