# Save user details from javascript into java

Tags: java, javascript, android

This is my situation:

I have a website stored in my mobile, I'm using "kws" to make my mobile as server, ofcourse when i turn on the hotspot in the mobile.

- When an user will connect to my hotspot he will type unique ip and port and then enter to my website.
- In my website there is place to leave details (email,phone number, name, etc..).

I actually want to take this details and send it to the java android program that is manages the website (i built android app to this mobile that manage the site, she switch the hotspot on/off ,etc..).

In the java code I want to get the details and write them to file or write them to my sqlite database in order to send it to specific email when i will be able to connect to the internet (when i connect to internet i turn off hotspot and the site isn't active anymore.)

The browsers it needs to support are: Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox.

How can i do it?  don't forgett that the only connection i have is the hotspot in the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to solve that i used Websockets. Now i can pass data from javascript to java.
I used this: [Writing a WebSocket Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900590/writing-a-websocket-server).