# How can I send and receive WebSocket messages on the server side?

Tags: encoding, protocols, websocket, decoding

- How can I send and receive messages on the server side using WebSocket, as per the protocol?
- Why do I get seemingly random bytes at the server when I send data from the browser to the server? It the data encoded somehow?
- How does the framing work in both the server → client and client → server directions?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

*Note: This is some explanation and pseudocode as to how to implement a very trivial server that can handle incoming and outcoming WebSocket messages as per the definitive framing format. It does not include the handshaking process. Furthermore, this answer has been made for educational purposes; it is not a full-featured implementation.*

[Specification (RFC 6455)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

---

### Sending messages

(In other words, server → browser)

The frames you're sending need to be formatted according to the WebSocket framing format. For sending messages, this format is as follows:

- one byte which contains the type of data (and some additional info which is out of scope for a trivial server)
- one byte which contains the length
- either two or eight bytes if the length does not fit in the second byte (the second byte is then a code saying how many bytes are used for the length)
- the actual (raw) data

The first byte will be `1000 0001` (or `129`) for a text frame.

The second byte has its first bit set to `0` because we're not encoding the data (encoding from server to client is not mandatory).

It is necessary to determine the length of the raw data so as to send the length bytes correctly:

- if `0 <= length <= 125`, you don't need additional bytes
- if `126 <= length <= 65535`, you need two additional bytes and the second byte is `126`
- if `length >= 65536`, you need eight additional bytes, and the second byte is `127`

The length has to be sliced into separate bytes, which means you'll need to bit-shift to the right (with an amount of eight bits), and then only retain the last eight bits by doing `AND 1111 1111` (which is `255`).

After the length byte(s) comes the raw data.

This leads to the following pseudocode:

```
bytesFormatted[0] = 129

indexStartRawData = -1 // it doesn't matter what value is
                       // set here - it will be set now:

if bytesRaw.length <= 125
    bytesFormatted[1] = bytesRaw.length

    indexStartRawData = 2

else if bytesRaw.length >= 126 and bytesRaw.length <= 65535
    bytesFormatted[1] = 126
    bytesFormatted[2] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 8 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[3] = ( bytesRaw.length      ) AND 255

    indexStartRawData = 4

else
    bytesFormatted[1] = 127
    bytesFormatted[2] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 56 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[3] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 48 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[4] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 40 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[5] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 32 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[6] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 24 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[7] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 16 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[8] = ( bytesRaw.length >>  8 ) AND 255
    bytesFormatted[9] = ( bytesRaw.length       ) AND 255

    indexStartRawData = 10

// put raw data at the correct index
bytesFormatted.put(bytesRaw, indexStartRawData)


// now send bytesFormatted (e.g. write it to the socket stream)
```

---

### Receiving messages

(In other words, browser → server)

The frames you obtain are in the following format:

- one byte which contains the type of data
- one byte which contains the length
- either two or eight additional bytes if the length did not fit in the second byte
- four bytes which are the masks (= decoding keys)
- the actual data

The first byte usually does not matter - if you're just sending text you are only using the text type. It will be `1000 0001` (or `129`) in that case.

The second byte and the additional two or eight bytes need some parsing, because you need to know how many bytes are used for the length (you need to know where the real data starts). The length itself is usually not necessary since you have the data already.

The first bit of the second byte is always `1` which means the data is masked (= encoded). Messages from the client to the server are always masked. You need to remove that first bit by doing `secondByte AND 0111 1111`. There are two cases in which the resulting byte does not represent the length because it did not fit in the second byte:

- a second byte of `0111 1110`, or `126`, means the following two bytes are used for the length
- a second byte of `0111 1111`, or `127`, means the following eight bytes are used for the length

The four mask bytes are used for decoding the actual data that has been sent. The algorithm for decoding is as follows:

```
decodedByte = encodedByte XOR masks[encodedByteIndex MOD 4]
```

where `encodedByte` is the original byte in the data, `encodedByteIndex` is the index (offset) of the byte counting from the first byte *of the real data*, which has index `0`. `masks` is an array containing of the four mask bytes.

This leads to the following pseudocode for decoding:

```
secondByte = bytes[1]

length = secondByte AND 127 // may not be the actual length in the two special cases

indexFirstMask = 2          // if not a special case

if length == 126            // if a special case, change indexFirstMask
    indexFirstMask = 4

else if length == 127       // ditto
    indexFirstMask = 10

masks = bytes.slice(indexFirstMask, 4) // four bytes starting from indexFirstMask

indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4 // four bytes further

decoded = new array

decoded.length = bytes.length - indexFirstDataByte // length of real data

for i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.length; i++, j++
    decoded[j] = bytes[i] XOR masks[j MOD 4]


// now use "decoded" to interpret the received data
```

Comment: Why `1000 0001` (129) for a text frame? The spec says says: `%x1 denotes a text frame`. So it should be `0000 0001` (`0x01`), or?

Comment: @Dennis: The frame opcode is `0001`, as it states at the header of that part of the specs: "Opcode:  4 bits". The first byte consists of FIN, RSV1-3 and opcode. FIN is `1`, RSV1-3 are all three `0` and the opcode is `0001` which adds up to `1000 0001` for the first byte. Also see the artwork in the specification which displays how the bytes are split up in the different parts.

Comment: You have a few lines that read like 'bytesFormatted[2] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 56 ) AND 255' in the Server->Client model - Would you mind breaking that down for me? AND seems to be a logical operator to me so I cant expect that simply putting a number after it will do anything for me in C#. Similarly, I'm not sure what the ">>" in your markup is supposed to indicate - however it does transfer over to C#... Whatever that means to me... :P

Comment: If anyone can clear this up for me actually, I'll be glad to post my C# implementation as an answer.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: I'm talking about the bitwise operators. So not `true && false` but rather `123 & 456` which will do a bitwise AND operation (there are tons of articles on the Internet on this). As for `x >> 56`, this means that `x` is looked at in binary, the last 56 bits are removed, and the remaining bits are interpreted as a number again. So `6 >> 2 == 1` because `6` in binary is `110`, and with the last two bits removed you end up with binary `1` which is `1`.

Comment: Awesome answer thank you! Helped me big time implemented my C++ Berkley Sockets implementation

Comment: @pimvdb, This is really a great answer. But I am confused the way you chose the masking key: `masks = bytes.slice(indexFirstMask, 4)`. According to the RFC, a masking key MUST be chosen at random and be unpredictable, but you slice 4 bytes from the data, which is predictable, and what if the length of the data is less than 4 bytes?

Comment: @Neevek: What they mean is that the mask bytes themselves need to be unpredictable. If they are constant there's not much point in them. Basically, when a malicious user has a slice of of data, he should not be able to decode it without the masks. If the masks *position* is not predictable then it's a bit difficult for the genuine server to decode :)

Comment: Note that if you want to send binary frames you should have `1000 0010`, or `0x80 | 0x02` (which I find more readable than `130`).

Comment: @pimvdb, Why does messages from client to server always be masked?

Answer (score 25):

Java implementation (if any one requires)

Reading : Client to Server

```
        int len = 0;            
        byte[] b = new byte[buffLenth];
        //rawIn is a Socket.getInputStream();
        while(true){
            len = rawIn.read(b);
            if(len!=-1){

                byte rLength = 0;
                int rMaskIndex = 2;
                int rDataStart = 0;
                //b[0] is always text in my case so no need to check;
                byte data = b[1];
                byte op = (byte) 127;
                rLength = (byte) (data & op);

                if(rLength==(byte)126) rMaskIndex=4;
                if(rLength==(byte)127) rMaskIndex=10;

                byte[] masks = new byte[4];

                int j=0;
                int i=0;
                for(i=rMaskIndex;i<(rMaskIndex+4);i++){
                    masks[j] = b[i];
                    j++;
                }

                rDataStart = rMaskIndex + 4;

                int messLen = len - rDataStart;

                byte[] message = new byte[messLen];

                for(i=rDataStart, j=0; i<len; i++, j++){
                    message[j] = (byte) (b[i] ^ masks[j % 4]);
                }

                parseMessage(new String(message)); 
                //parseMessage(new String(b));

                b = new byte[buffLenth];

            }
        }
```

Writing : Server to Client

```
public void brodcast(String mess) throws IOException{
    byte[] rawData = mess.getBytes();

    int frameCount  = 0;
    byte[] frame = new byte[10];

    frame[0] = (byte) 129;

    if(rawData.length <= 125){
        frame[1] = (byte) rawData.length;
        frameCount = 2;
    }else if(rawData.length >= 126 && rawData.length <= 65535){
        frame[1] = (byte) 126;
        int len = rawData.length;
        frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[3] = (byte)(len & (byte)255); 
        frameCount = 4;
    }else{
        frame[1] = (byte) 127;
        int len = rawData.length;
        frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 56 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[3] = (byte)((len >> 48 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[4] = (byte)((len >> 40 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[5] = (byte)((len >> 32 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[6] = (byte)((len >> 24 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[7] = (byte)((len >> 16 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[8] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[9] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
        frameCount = 10;
    }

    int bLength = frameCount + rawData.length;

    byte[] reply = new byte[bLength];

    int bLim = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<frameCount;i++){
        reply[bLim] = frame[i];
        bLim++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rawData.length;i++){
        reply[bLim] = rawData[i];
        bLim++;
    }

    out.write(reply);
    out.flush();

}
```

Comment: What would be an appropriate buffer length for the read operation?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I just copied void broadcast (from Server to Client) to my program. Socket connected successfully, message sent to browser successfully, but nothing received by browser.

Comment: Writing : Server to Client -> is not working ..
see my Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75523083/java-with-websocket-connection-is-working-but-i-could-not-send-a-message

Answer (score 18):

JavaScript implementation:

```js
function encodeWebSocket(bytesRaw) {
  var bytesFormatted = new Array();
  bytesFormatted[0] = 129;
  if (bytesRaw.length <= 125) {
      bytesFormatted[1] = bytesRaw.length;
  } else if (bytesRaw.length >= 126 && bytesRaw.length <= 65535) {
      bytesFormatted[1] = 126;
      bytesFormatted[2] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 8 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[3] = ( bytesRaw.length      ) & 255;
  } else {
      bytesFormatted[1] = 127;
      bytesFormatted[2] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 56 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[3] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 48 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[4] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 40 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[5] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 32 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[6] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 24 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[7] = ( bytesRaw.length >> 16 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[8] = ( bytesRaw.length >>  8 ) & 255;
      bytesFormatted[9] = ( bytesRaw.length       ) & 255;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < bytesRaw.length; i++) {
      bytesFormatted.push(bytesRaw.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return bytesFormatted;
}

function decodeWebSocket (data) {
  var datalength = data[1] & 127;
  var indexFirstMask = 2;
  if (datalength == 126) {
      indexFirstMask = 4;
  } else if (datalength == 127) {
      indexFirstMask = 10;
  }
  var masks = data.slice(indexFirstMask,indexFirstMask + 4);
  var i = indexFirstMask + 4;
  var index = 0;
  var output = "";
  while (i < data.length) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(data[i++] ^ masks[index++ % 4]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that JavaScript doesn't actually support shifting with numbers bigger than `2^31 - 1`.

Answer (score 13):

C# Implementation

Browser -> Server

```
    private String DecodeMessage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        String incomingData = String.Empty;
        Byte secondByte = bytes[1];
        Int32 dataLength = secondByte & 127;
        Int32 indexFirstMask = 2;
        if (dataLength == 126)
            indexFirstMask = 4;
        else if (dataLength == 127)
            indexFirstMask = 10;

        IEnumerable<Byte> keys = bytes.Skip(indexFirstMask).Take(4);
        Int32 indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4;

        Byte[] decoded = new Byte[bytes.Length - indexFirstDataByte];
        for (Int32 i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            decoded[j] = (Byte)(bytes[i] ^ keys.ElementAt(j % 4));
        }

        return incomingData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
    }
```

Server -> Browser

```
    private static Byte[] EncodeMessageToSend(String message)
    {
        Byte[] response;
        Byte[] bytesRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        Byte[] frame = new Byte[10];

        Int32 indexStartRawData = -1;
        Int32 length = bytesRaw.Length;

        frame[0] = (Byte)129;
        if (length <= 125)
        {
            frame[1] = (Byte)length;
            indexStartRawData = 2;
        }
        else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535)
        {
            frame[1] = (Byte)126;
            frame[2] = (Byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[3] = (Byte)(length & 255);
            indexStartRawData = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            frame[1] = (Byte)127;
            frame[2] = (Byte)((length >> 56) & 255);
            frame[3] = (Byte)((length >> 48) & 255);
            frame[4] = (Byte)((length >> 40) & 255);
            frame[5] = (Byte)((length >> 32) & 255);
            frame[6] = (Byte)((length >> 24) & 255);
            frame[7] = (Byte)((length >> 16) & 255);
            frame[8] = (Byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[9] = (Byte)(length & 255);

            indexStartRawData = 10;
        }

        response = new Byte[indexStartRawData + length];

        Int32 i, reponseIdx = 0;

        //Add the frame bytes to the reponse
        for (i = 0; i < indexStartRawData; i++)
        {
            response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
            reponseIdx++;
        }

        //Add the data bytes to the response
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
            reponseIdx++;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: The decode function always return my specific message with an for me undefined appendix like here `test�c=ܝX[` in which "test" is my message. What is the other part coming from?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I created a small C# application(Console and Web) to try out web sockets. You can download them from here to see how it is coded. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw8hjsov1u6f7c0/Web%20Sockets.rar?dl=0

Comment: This failed for me on large messages. I replaced the length > 65535 code with:

    var l = Convert.ToUInt64(length);
    var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(l);
    Array.Reverse(b, 0, b.Length);
    b.CopyTo(frame,2);

...which seems to have fixed things.

Comment: Good job. Only one thing: On DecodeMessage i'm calculating "decoded" array length based on the Payload length data that is included on the dataframe becasue "bytes" array length could not be exact. "bytes" array length depends of the way the stream is readed.

Comment: @Sean can you show me your full example for fix large message problem? i cannot change that code to your sample.

Comment: what is client side encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 6):

pimvdb's answer implemented in python:

```
def DecodedCharArrayFromByteStreamIn(stringStreamIn):
    #turn string values into opererable numeric byte values
    byteArray = [ord(character) for character in stringStreamIn]
    datalength = byteArray[1] & 127
    indexFirstMask = 2 
    if datalength == 126:
        indexFirstMask = 4
    elif datalength == 127:
        indexFirstMask = 10
    masks = [m for m in byteArray[indexFirstMask : indexFirstMask+4]]
    indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
    decodedChars = []
    i = indexFirstDataByte
    j = 0
    while i < len(byteArray):
        decodedChars.append( chr(byteArray[i] ^ masks[j % 4]) )
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return decodedChars
```

An Example of usage:

```
fromclient = '\x81\x8c\xff\xb8\xbd\xbd\xb7\xdd\xd1\xd1\x90\x98\xea\xd2\x8d\xd4\xd9\x9c'
# this looks like "?ŒOÇ¿¢gÓ ç\Ð=«ož" in unicode, received by server
print DecodedCharArrayFromByteStreamIn(fromclient)
# ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

Comment: I tried to use your code in my script, but with no success. Could you perhaps be able to help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748377/websocket-response-decoding-decode-returns-an-empty-string-instead-of-message

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the PHP frame encoding function, here follows a decode function:

```
function Decode($M){
    $M = array_map("ord", str_split($M));
    $L = $M[1] AND 127;

    if ($L == 126)
        $iFM = 4;
    else if ($L == 127)
        $iFM = 10;
    else
        $iFM = 2;

    $Masks = array_slice($M, $iFM, 4);

    $Out = "";
    for ($i = $iFM + 4, $j = 0; $i < count($M); $i++, $j++ ) {
        $Out .= chr($M[$i] ^ $Masks[$j % 4]);
    }
    return $Out;
}
```

I've implemented this and also other functions in an easy-to-use WebSocket PHP class [here](https://github.com/nVentis/PHP-WebSocketServer).

Answer (score 4):

PHP Implementation:

```
function encode($message)
{
    $length = strlen($message);

    $bytesHeader = [];
    $bytesHeader[0] = 129; // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)

    if ($length <= 125) {
            $bytesHeader[1] = $length;
    } else if ($length >= 126 && $length <= 65535) {
            $bytesHeader[1] = 126;
            $bytesHeader[2] = ( $length >> 8 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[3] = ( $length      ) & 255;
    } else {
            $bytesHeader[1] = 127;
            $bytesHeader[2] = ( $length >> 56 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[3] = ( $length >> 48 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[4] = ( $length >> 40 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[5] = ( $length >> 32 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[6] = ( $length >> 24 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[7] = ( $length >> 16 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[8] = ( $length >>  8 ) & 255;
            $bytesHeader[9] = ( $length       ) & 255;
    }

    $str = implode(array_map("chr", $bytesHeader)) . $message;

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the answer, i would like to add onto ***hfern's***(above) Python version to include the Sending function if any one is interested.

```
def DecodedWebsockRecieve(stringStreamIn):
    byteArray =  stringStreamIn 
    datalength = byteArray[1] & 127
    indexFirstMask = 2 
    if datalength == 126:
        indexFirstMask = 4
    elif datalength == 127:
        indexFirstMask = 10
    masks = [m for m in byteArray[indexFirstMask : indexFirstMask+4]]
    indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
    decodedChars = []
    i = indexFirstDataByte
    j = 0
    while i < len(byteArray):
        decodedChars.append( chr(byteArray[i] ^ masks[j % 4]) )
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return ''.join(decodedChars)

def EncodeWebSockSend(socket,data):
    bytesFormatted = []
    bytesFormatted.append(129)

    bytesRaw = data.encode()
    bytesLength = len(bytesRaw)
    if bytesLength <= 125 :
        bytesFormatted.append(bytesLength)
    elif bytesLength >= 126 and bytesLength <= 65535 :
        bytesFormatted.append(126)
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 8 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( bytesLength & 255 )
    else :
        bytesFormatted.append( 127 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 56 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 48 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 40 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 32 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 24 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >> 16 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( ( bytesLength >>  8 ) & 255 )
        bytesFormatted.append( bytesLength & 255 )

    bytesFormatted = bytes(bytesFormatted)
    bytesFormatted = bytesFormatted + bytesRaw
    socket.send(bytesFormatted)
```

Usage for reading:

```
bufSize = 1024     
read = DecodedWebsockRecieve(socket.recv(bufSize))
```

Usage for writing:

```
EncodeWebSockSend(sock,"hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation in Go

Encode part (server -> browser)

```
func encode (message string) (result []byte) {
  rawBytes := []byte(message)
  var idxData int

  length := byte(len(rawBytes))
  if len(rawBytes) <= 125 { //one byte to store data length
    result = make([]byte, len(rawBytes) + 2)
    result[1] = length
    idxData = 2
  } else if len(rawBytes) >= 126 && len(rawBytes) <= 65535 { //two bytes to store data length
    result = make([]byte, len(rawBytes) + 4)
    result[1] = 126 //extra storage needed
    result[2] = ( length >> 8 ) & 255
    result[3] = ( length      ) & 255
    idxData = 4
  } else {
    result = make([]byte, len(rawBytes) + 10)
    result[1] = 127
    result[2] = ( length >> 56 ) & 255
    result[3] = ( length >> 48 ) & 255
    result[4] = ( length >> 40 ) & 255
    result[5] = ( length >> 32 ) & 255
    result[6] = ( length >> 24 ) & 255
    result[7] = ( length >> 16 ) & 255
    result[8] = ( length >>  8 ) & 255
    result[9] = ( length       ) & 255
    idxData = 10
  }

  result[0] = 129 //only text is supported

  // put raw data at the correct index
  for i, b := range rawBytes {
    result[idxData + i] = b
  }
  return
}
```

Decode part (browser -> server)

```
func decode (rawBytes []byte) string {
  var idxMask int
  if rawBytes[1] == 126 {
    idxMask = 4
  } else if rawBytes[1] == 127 {
    idxMask = 10
  } else {
    idxMask = 2
  }

  masks := rawBytes[idxMask:idxMask + 4]
  data := rawBytes[idxMask + 4:len(rawBytes)]
  decoded := make([]byte, len(rawBytes) - idxMask + 4)

  for i, b := range data {
    decoded[i] = b ^ masks[i % 4]
  }
  return string(decoded)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Clojure, the decode function assumes frame is sent as map of `{:data byte-array-buffer :size int-size-of-buffer}`, because the actual size may not be the same size as the byte-array depending on chunk size of your inputstream.

Code posted here: https://gist.github.com/viperscape/8918565

```
(defn ws-decode [frame]
  "decodes websocket frame"
  (let [data (:data frame)
        dlen (bit-and (second data) 127)
        mstart (if (== dlen 127) 10 (if (== dlen 126) 4 2))
        mask (drop 2 (take (+ mstart 4) data))
        msg (make-array Byte/TYPE (- (:size frame) (+ mstart 4)))]
   (loop [i (+ mstart 4), j 0]
      (aset-byte msg j (byte (bit-xor (nth data i) (nth mask (mod j 4)))))
      (if (< i (dec(:size frame))) (recur (inc i) (inc j))))
    msg))

(defn ws-encode [data]
  "takes in bytes, return websocket frame"
  (let [len (count data)
        blen (if (> len 65535) 10 (if (> len 125) 4 2))
        buf (make-array Byte/TYPE (+ len blen))
        _ (aset-byte buf 0 -127) ;;(bit-or (unchecked-byte 0x80) 
                                           (unchecked-byte 0x1)
        _ (if (= 2 blen) 
            (aset-byte buf 1 len) ;;mask 0, len
            (do
              (dorun(map #(aset-byte buf %1 
                      (unchecked-byte (bit-and (bit-shift-right len (*(- %2 2) 8))
                                               255)))
                      (range 2 blen) (into ()(range 2 blen))))
              (aset-byte buf 1 (if (> blen 4) 127 126))))
        _ (System/arraycopy data 0 buf blen len)]
    buf))
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Implementation (not by me) [here](https://github.com/katzarsky/WebSocket). Note that when your bytes are over 65535, you need to shift with a long value as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25043422/645583).

Answer (score 0):

Updated [Haribabu Pasupathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679439) code to deal with TCP segmentation. In my case websocket packets larger than 1024 bytes sent by browser are being splitted into TCP segments, so reassembling is required.

```
private static void processResponse(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    int readPacketLength = 0;
    byte[] packet = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream packetStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while(true) {
        readPacketLength = inputStream.read(packet);

        if(readPacketLength != -1) {
            if ((packet[0] & (byte) 15) == (byte) 8) { // Disconnect packet
                outputStream.write(packet, 0, readPacketLength);
                // returning the same packet for client to terminate connection
                outputStream.flush();
                return;
            }
            byte messageLengthByte = 0;
            int messageLength = 0;
            int maskIndex = 2;
            int messageStart = 0;
            //b[0] is always text in my case so no need to check;
            byte data = packet[1];
            byte op = (byte) 127; // 0111 111
            messageLengthByte = (byte) (data & op);

            int totalPacketLength = 0;
            if (messageLengthByte == (byte) 126 || messageLengthByte == (byte) 127) {
                if (messageLengthByte == (byte) 126) {
                    maskIndex = 4;
                    // if (messageLengthInt==(byte)126), then 16-bit length is stored in packet[2] and [3]
                    ByteBuffer messageLength16Bit = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
                    messageLength16Bit.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
                    messageLength16Bit.put((byte) 0x00);
                    messageLength16Bit.put((byte) 0x00);
                    messageLength16Bit.put(packet, 2, 2);
                    messageLength16Bit.flip();
                    messageLength = messageLength16Bit.getInt();
                    totalPacketLength = messageLength + 8;
                } else {
                    maskIndex = 10;
                    // if (messageLengthInt==(byte)127), then 64-bit length is stored in bytes [2] to [9]. Using only 32-bit
                    ByteBuffer messageLength64Bit = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
                    messageLength64Bit.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
                    messageLength64Bit.put(packet, 6, 4);
                    messageLength64Bit.flip();
                    messageLength = messageLength64Bit.getInt();
                    totalPacketLength = messageLength + 14;
                }

                if (readPacketLength != totalPacketLength) {
                    packetStream.write(packet, 0, readPacketLength);

                    int lastPacketLength = 0;
                    while (readPacketLength < totalPacketLength) {
                        packet = new byte[1024];
                        readPacketLength += lastPacketLength = inputStream.read(packet);
                        packetStream.write(packet, 0, lastPacketLength);
                    }
                    packet = packetStream.toByteArray();
                    packetStream.reset();
                }
            }
            else { // using message length from packet[1]
                messageLength = messageLengthByte;
            }

            byte[] masks = new byte[4];
            int i=0; int j=0;
            for(i = maskIndex; i < (maskIndex+4); i++) {
                masks[j] = packet[i];
                j++;
            }

            messageStart = maskIndex + 4;

            byte[] message = new byte[messageLength];
            for(i = messageStart, j = 0; i < readPacketLength; i++, j++){
                message[j] = (byte) (packet[i] ^ masks[j % 4]);
            }
            System.out.println("Received message: " + new String(message));
            packet = new byte[1024];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the > 65535 message length issue from Nitij's C# implementation.

```
private static Byte[] EncodeMessageToSend(String message)
{
    Byte[] response;
    Byte[] bytesRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    Byte[] frame = new Byte[10];

    Int32 indexStartRawData = -1;
    Int32 length = bytesRaw.Length;

    frame[0] = (Byte)129;
    if (length <= 125)
    {
        frame[1] = (Byte)length;
        indexStartRawData = 2;
    }
    else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535)
    {
        frame[1] = (Byte)126;
        frame[2] = (Byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
        frame[3] = (Byte)(length & 255);
        indexStartRawData = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        var lengthAsULong = Convert.ToUInt64(length);
        frame[1] = 127;
        frame[2] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 56) & 255);
        frame[3] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 48) & 255);
        frame[4] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 40) & 255);
        frame[5] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 32) & 255);
        frame[6] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 24) & 255);
        frame[7] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 16) & 255);
        frame[8] = (byte)((lengthAsULong >> 8) & 255);
        frame[9] = (byte)(lengthAsULong & 255);

        indexStartRawData = 10;
    }

    response = new Byte[indexStartRawData + length];

    Int32 i, reponseIdx = 0;

    //Add the frame bytes to the reponse
    for (i = 0; i < indexStartRawData; i++)
    {
        response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
        reponseIdx++;
    }

    //Add the data bytes to the response
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
        reponseIdx++;
    }

    return response;
}
```