# Send data to clients

Tags: c#, websocket

I was using older version of handshake(with two keys) and everything was fine. Now I'm creating Sec-WebSocket-Accept key, and manage to connect to the server. But as soon as I send message to connected client, it get disconnected.
I guess those lines of code are wrong, but I can not find working example of sending data(examples are mainly for older WS version)

```
ConnectionSocket.Send(New Byte() {CByte(WrapperBytes.Start)}, 1, 0)
ConnectionSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
ConnectionSocket.Send(New Byte() {CByte(WrapperBytes.[End])}, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [latest draft of the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5) for how to send/receive data now.

It'd also be worth checking [which version of web sockets](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket) is supported by your browser.

In case it helps, I've written a [C++ example](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/OpenHome/Net/Device/Upnp/DviServerWebSocket.cpp).  The WsProtocol80 class shows how to read/write data.

Comment: Thanks,can not read c++...vb or c# will be great. I have read many articles and specification but can not manage code to work. Simple "Hello world" will do the magic.

Comment: Which version of web sockets are you trying to implement now?  (Or, alternatively, which browser/version are you testing with?)
Assuming v8 or later for web sockets, [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages) was answered with pseudocode showing how to send & receive messages.

Comment: draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-15 and chrome v15

Comment: Thanks.  The [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages) should cover things for you then.