# WebSocket server in Python: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, python-import

I am trying to run this simple Python WebSocket, with a couple very minor changes. I am running Python 2.4.3 because I cannot use an newer version, but I'm not sure how much that matters.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket.py", line 258, in ?
    server = WebSocketServer("localhost", 8000, WebSocket)
  File "socket.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

And here is my code:

```
import time
import struct
import socket
import base64
import sys
from select import select
import re
import logging
from threading import Thread
import signal

# Simple WebSocket server implementation. Handshakes with the client then echos back everything
# that is received. Has no dependencies (doesn't require Twisted etc) and works with the RFC6455
# version of WebSockets. Tested with FireFox 16, though should work with the latest versions of
# IE, Chrome etc.
#
# rich20b@gmail.com
# Adapted from https://gist.github.com/512987 with various functions stolen from other sites, see
# below for full details.

# Constants
MAGICGUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
TEXT = 0x01
BINARY = 0x02


# WebSocket implementation
class WebSocket(object):

    handshake = (
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n"
        "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n"
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %(acceptstring)s\r\n"
        "Server: TestTest\r\n"
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost\r\n"
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n"
        "\r\n"
    )


    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, client, server):
        self.client = client
        self.server = server
        self.handshaken = False
        self.header = ""
        self.data = ""


    # Serve this client
    def feed(self, data):

        # If we haven't handshaken yet
        if not self.handshaken:
            logging.debug("No handshake yet")
            self.header += data
            if self.header.find('\r\n\r\n') != -1:
                parts = self.header.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)
                self.header = parts[0]
                if self.dohandshake(self.header, parts[1]):
                    logging.info("Handshake successful")
                    self.handshaken = True

        # We have handshaken
        else:
            logging.debug("Handshake is complete")

            # Decode the data that we received according to section 5 of RFC6455
            recv = self.decodeCharArray(data)

            # Send our reply
            self.sendMessage(''.join(recv).strip());


    # Stolen from http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldsd/docs/spring2012-csci4220/websocket-py.txt
    def sendMessage(self, s):
        """
        Encode and send a WebSocket message
        """

        # Empty message to start with
        message = ""

        # always send an entire message as one frame (fin)
        b1 = 0x80

        # in Python 2, strs are bytes and unicodes are strings
        if type(s) == unicode:
            b1 |= TEXT
            payload = s.encode("UTF8")

        elif type(s) == str:
            b1 |= TEXT
            payload = s

        # Append 'FIN' flag to the message
        message += chr(b1)

        # never mask frames from the server to the client
        b2 = 0

        # How long is our payload?
        length = len(payload)
        if length < 126:
            b2 |= length
            message += chr(b2)

        elif length < (2 ** 16) - 1:
            b2 |= 126
            message += chr(b2)
            l = struct.pack(">H", length)
            message += l

        else:
            l = struct.pack(">Q", length)
            b2 |= 127
            message += chr(b2)
            message += l

        # Append payload to message
        message += payload

        # Send to the client
        self.client.send(str(message))


    # Stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side
    def decodeCharArray(self, stringStreamIn):

        # Turn string values into opererable numeric byte values
        byteArray = [ord(character) for character in stringStreamIn]
        datalength = byteArray[1] & 127
        indexFirstMask = 2

        if datalength == 126:
            indexFirstMask = 4
        elif datalength == 127:
            indexFirstMask = 10

        # Extract masks
        masks = [m for m in byteArray[indexFirstMask : indexFirstMask+4]]
        indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4

        # List of decoded characters
        decodedChars = []
        i = indexFirstDataByte
        j = 0

        # Loop through each byte that was received
        while i < len(byteArray):

            # Unmask this byte and add to the decoded buffer
            decodedChars.append( chr(byteArray[i] ^ masks[j % 4]) )
            i += 1
            j += 1

        # Return the decoded string
        return decodedChars


    # Handshake with this client
    def dohandshake(self, header, key=None):

        logging.debug("Begin handshake: %s" % header)

        # Get the handshake template
        handshake = self.handshake

        # Step through each header
        for line in header.split('\r\n')[1:]:
            name, value = line.split(': ', 1)

            # If this is the key
            if name.lower() == "sec-websocket-key":

                # Append the standard GUID and get digest
                combined = value + MAGICGUID
                response = base64.b64encode(combined.digest())

                # Replace the placeholder in the handshake response
                handshake = handshake % { 'acceptstring' : response }

        logging.debug("Sending handshake %s" % handshake)
        self.client.send(handshake)
        return True

    def onmessage(self, data):
        #logging.info("Got message: %s" % data)
        self.send(data)

    def send(self, data):
        logging.info("Sent message: %s" % data)
        self.client.send("\x00%s\xff" % data)

    def close(self):
        self.client.close()


# WebSocket server implementation
class WebSocketServer(object):

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, bind, port, cls):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind((bind, port))
        self.bind = bind
        self.port = port
        self.cls = cls
        self.connections = {}
        self.listeners = [self.socket]

    # Listen for requests
    def listen(self, backlog=5):

        self.socket.listen(backlog)
        logging.info("Listening on %s" % self.port)

        # Keep serving requests
        self.running = True
        while self.running:

            # Find clients that need servicing
            rList, wList, xList = select(self.listeners, [], self.listeners, 1)
            for ready in rList:
                if ready == self.socket:
                    logging.debug("New client connection")
                    client, address = self.socket.accept()
                    fileno = client.fileno()
                    self.listeners.append(fileno)
                    self.connections[fileno] = self.cls(client, self)
                else:
                    logging.debug("Client ready for reading %s" % ready)
                    client = self.connections[ready].client
                    data = client.recv(4096)
                    fileno = client.fileno()
                    if data:
                        self.connections[fileno].feed(data)
                    else:
                        logging.debug("Closing client %s" % ready)
                        self.connections[fileno].close()
                        del self.connections[fileno]
                        self.listeners.remove(ready)

            # Step though and delete broken connections
            for failed in xList:
                if failed == self.socket:
                    logging.error("Socket broke")
                    for fileno, conn in self.connections:
                        conn.close()
                    self.running = False

# Entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    server = WebSocketServer("localhost", 8000, WebSocket)
    server_thread = Thread(target=server.listen, args=[5])
    server_thread.start()

    # Add SIGINT handler for killing the threads
    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        logging.info("Caught Ctrl+C, shutting down...")
        server.running = False
        sys.exit()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    while True:
        time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: I made the same mistake  - really glad I found your question!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It appears that you've named your own file `socket.py`, so when you `import socket`, you're not getting the system library (it's just re-importing the file you're currently in - which has no `AF_INET` symbol).  Try renaming your file something like `mysocket.py`.

Comment: @Gus: they're the hardest ones to see sometimes :-)

Comment: @NickBastin Thanks! I would have never imagined my file name is going to mess with module imports! interestingly all noobs think alike :) and name their socket intro program as 'socket.py' :) ... I was scratching my head... and restarting my editors/cli/terminal (yup tats my noob solution to all problems!) but glad did google search before restarting my PC and found this!

Comment: the most deserved upvote I ever gave

Answer (score 27):

Even after changing the file name, if you are running the python from the terminal.

(you may get the same error)

Kindly

```
rm -rf socket.pyc
```

(previously compiled bytecode)

Comment: Great contribution, this really helped me. Thank you so much :D +rep

Comment: This was from long ago, but this too helped me with an issue. I was seeing --- Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'socket' --- And and found my python 2.7's version of socket.pyc and deleted it. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, I was literally stuck here for hours, tried re installing it a million times, but found the solution.

1) Make sure the file name is not socket.py,

2) Change the directory, it will not work in the home directory due to some permission issues.

If you have by anychance saved the file as socket.py, do not copy the same file or rename it to something else, the problem will persist.
What I advice you to do is, open a new folder in a different directory, write a simple socket code which involved AF_INET. Try to run it. It should work.

Comment: aaah.. i did the same mistake of copying it to different name in same directory too ! all noobs think alike!

Answer (score 3):

Issue can be that you have a file or Cache name socket.py or socket.pyc

```
rm -rf socket.py
rm -rf socket.pyc
```

Hopefully this will resolve your import issue. Gud Luck

Comment: thanks it helped.

Comment: How does this answer add to any of the previous ones?

Answer (score 2):

enter the current working directory 
and remove the files named 'socket.py' and 'socket.pyc'