# python give me a "socket error" when i'm using requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, python-sockets

I don't know why when I try to import and use the requests module it gives me an error.
I don't understand why the problem talks about the socket module.

This is the error:
[image: this is the error]

Comment: Rename your socket.py file to something else. Part of the code of the requests module is trying to import the built-in socket module, but is importing yours instead.

Comment: Also, please post console output as **TEXT**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSocket server in Python: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF\_INET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755963/websocket-server-in-python-module-object-has-no-attribute-af-inet)