# WebSocket frame decoding in Python

Tags: python, websocket, decode, mask

I've tried to implement WebSocket frame unmasking algorithm (based on this: [How can I send and receive WebSocket messages on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side)) on the server side. Here's what I've got:

```
def decode(data):
    frame = bytearray(data)

    length = frame[1] & 127

    indexFirstMask = 2
    if length == 126:
        indexFirstMask = 4
    elif length == 127:
        indexFirstMask = 10

    indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
    mask = frame[indexFirstMask:indexFirstDataByte]

    i = indexFirstDataByte
    j = 0
    decoded = []
    while i < len(frame):
        decoded.append(frame[i] ^ mask[j%4])
        i += 1
        j += 1

    print decoded

    return "".join(chr(byte) for byte in decoded)
```

However I get very strange results. On JavaScript side:

```
w = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000");
w.send("test");
w.send("test");
w.send("test");
w.send("test");
```

produces on the server side:

```
[42, 73, 45, 46, 1, 0]
[42, 1, 98, 0, 0]
[2, 97, 0, 0]
[2, 97, 0, 0]
```

More calls to `w.send("test");` produces `[2, 97, 0, 0]`. Also first two arrays have length >4 (number of characters in word `test`). And none of these gets converted to word `test`. It seeems that I must be doing something wrong in my decoding code. What's causing that? Any help?

**EDIT** Have look at raw frames:

```
[193, 134, 48, 166, 232, 11, 26, 239, 197, 37, 49, 166]
[193, 133, 57, 161, 169, 218, 19, 160, 203, 218, 57]
[193, 132, 150, 97, 124, 54, 148, 0, 124, 54]
[193, 132, 163, 26, 102, 249, 161, 123, 102, 249]
[193, 132, 238, 212, 210, 156, 236, 181, 210, 156]
```

Of course these numbers are a bit random (due to masking), but note that second byte (which is supposed to represent the length of payload) is `134`, then `133` and then always `132`. Also first two frames are longer then other frames. What's going on here?

Comment: Please have a look at this answer it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778823/1193863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just looked at this frames one more time and I've realized that the first byte:

```
193[DEC] == 11000001[BIN]
```

which according to the specification means that `RSV1` is used (the second bit is `1`). This seems to mean that the extension is used and indeed in my handshake code I've found the following line:

```
ext = req.headers.get("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "").strip()
if ext:
    res += "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: %s\r\n" % ext
```

and in Chrome I can see:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

when I do the handshake.

I'm not sure yet how these extensions work but removing these 3 lines from the handshake code fixes the issue.