# Payload size larger than 125 bytes

Tags: python, html, websocket, byte

I am using this function to decode a package sent via html5 websockets
But when the payload goes over 125 bytes it crashes.
Is it possible to make it larger?

---

```
def decode_data(data):
  databyte = bytearray(data)
  datalen = (0x7F & databyte[1])
  str_data = ''
  if(datalen > 0):
    mask_key = databyte[2:6]
    masked_data = databyte[6:(6+datalen)]
    unmasked_data = [masked_data[i] ^ mask_key[i%4] for i in range(len(masked_data))]
    str_data = str(bytearray(unmasked_data))
  return str_data
```

Comment: For anyone thats looking:

      def decode_data(data):
        if not len(data):
            return False
        length = ord(data[1]) & 127
        if length == 126:
            mask = data[4:8]
            raw = data[8:]
        elif length == 127:
            mask = data[10:14]
            raw = data[14:]
        else:
            mask = data[2:6]
            raw = data[6:]
        ret = ''
        for cnt, d in enumerate(raw):
            ret += chr(ord(d) ^ ord(mask[cnt%4]))
        return ret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of making it longer. Per the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2):

> - If the length is 0-125, that is the payload length.
> - If 126, the following 2 bytes interpreted as a 16-bit unsigned    integer are the payload length.
> - If 127, the following 8 bytes interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned    integer (the most significant bit MUST be 0) are the payload length.

The length has to be sliced into separate bytes, which means you'll need to bit-shift to the right (with an amount of eight bits), and then only retain the last eight bits by doing and `1111 1111` (which is `255`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125509/1272394) goes over this principal in great detail.