# Read WebSocket client data to the server vb.net

Tags: websocket, vb.net-2010

Good afternoon. I clarify that I don't know much about WebSockets, but I'm learning about it. I am trying to make a connection between vb.net (server) and browser (client) using WebSocket. Searching on the internet I could make this work ([Websocket Server VB.NET - Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931276/websocket-server-vb-net-data-frame)) Currently I can send a message from vb.net to the browser, but I have not known how to read the messages that the client sends to the server .. I found a code about it, but I do not understand well how it could be implemented to my code ([WebSocket Server, client -> server frame mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721957/websocket-server-client-server-frame-mask))

CLIENT

```
function connect(host) {
  var ws = new WebSocket(host);
  ws.onopen = function () {
    console('connected');
    //ws.send("test");
  };

  ws.onmessage = function (evt) {  
    console('reveived data:'+evt.data);
  };

  ws.onclose = function () {
    console('socket closed');
  };
```

SERVER

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
    Dim serverTcp As TcpListener
    Dim serverThread As Thread
    Dim host_ As String = ""
    Dim curSocket As Socket
    Sub Main()
        '' Start server
        serverThread = New Thread(AddressOf serverProc)
        serverThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub serverProc()
        Try
            '' Listen to port 5665
            serverTcp = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(host_), 5665)
            serverTcp.Start()

            Console.WriteLine("Listen to port 5665 ...")

            '' Accept any connection
            While (True)
                curSocket = serverTcp.AcceptSocket()
                Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf clientProc)
                thread.Start(curSocket)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub clientProc(ByVal sck As Socket)
        Try
            Dim netStream As New NetworkStream(sck)
            Dim netReader As New IO.StreamReader(netStream)
            Dim netWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(netStream)

            Dim key As String = ""

            Console.WriteLine("Accept new connection ...")

            '' Reading handshake message
            While (True)
                Dim line As String = netReader.ReadLine()
                If line.Length = 0 Then
                    Exit While
                End If

                If (line.StartsWith("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")) Then
                    key = line.Split(":")(1).Trim()
                End If

                Console.WriteLine("Data: " & line)

            End While

            '' Calculate accept-key
            key += "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
            key = getSHA1Hash(key)

            '' Response handshake message
            Dim response As String
            response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & vbCrLf
            response &= "Upgrade: websocket" & vbCrLf
            response &= "Connection: Upgrade" & vbCrLf
            response &= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & key & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            netWriter.Write(response)
            netWriter.Flush()

            '' Sending message
            SendMessage(sck, "SEND.. VB.NET")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    Sub Msg(t As String)
        Console.WriteLine(t)
    End Sub
    Function getSHA1Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
        Dim sha1Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)
        Dim result As String

        bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
        result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToHash)

        Return result
    End Function

    Sub SendMessage(sck As Socket, message As String)
        Dim rawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)

        Dim frameCount = 0
        Dim frame(10) As Byte

        frame(0) = CByte(129)

        If rawData.Length <= 125 Then
            frame(1) = CByte(rawData.Length)
            frameCount = 2
        ElseIf rawData.Length >= 126 AndAlso rawData.Length <= 65535 Then
            frame(1) = CByte(126)
            Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length)
            frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
            frame(3) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
            frameCount = 4
        Else
            frame(1) = CByte(127)
            Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length)
            frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 56) & CByte(255)))
            frame(3) = CByte(((len >> 48) & CByte(255)))
            frame(4) = CByte(((len >> 40) & CByte(255)))
            frame(5) = CByte(((len >> 32) & CByte(255)))
            frame(6) = CByte(((len >> 24) & CByte(255)))
            frame(7) = CByte(((len >> 16) & CByte(255)))
            frame(8) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
            frame(9) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
            frameCount = 10
        End If

        Dim bLength = frameCount + rawData.Length
        Console.WriteLine(frameCount)
        Console.WriteLine(rawData.Length)
        Dim reply(bLength + 1) As Byte

        Dim bLim = 0
        For i = 0 To frameCount - 1
            Console.WriteLine(bLim)
            reply(bLim) = frame(i)
            bLim += 1
        Next

        For i = 0 To rawData.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(bLim)
            reply(bLim) = rawData(i)
            bLim += 1
        Next

        sck.Send(reply)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        host_ = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList _
    .Where(Function(a As IPAddress) Not a.IsIPv6LinkLocal AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6Multicast AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6SiteLocal) _
    .Last() _
    .ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Main()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnviarMensaje_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnviarMensaje.Click
        SendMessage(curSocket, txtMensaje.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

it is simple if you want implement this in your vb.net project
you have to put this code anywhere in your project to calling
you also can use it as a "clientProc" private sub or you also
can insert this code in button1 object if you will click on button
after handshake it will give you return web browser websocket client message

```
 Dim netStream As New NetworkStream(curSocket)
        Dim bytesArray(1024) As [Byte]
        Dim byteslen As Int32
        byteslen = netStream.Read(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length)

        If bytesArray.Length > 1 Then
            Msg("---------------------------------------------------")
            Msg("data type: " & bytesArray(0))

            Dim secondByte As Byte = bytesArray(1)
            Dim theLength As UInteger = secondByte And 127
            Dim indexFirstMask As Integer = 2
            If theLength = 126 Then
                indexFirstMask = 4
            ElseIf theLength = 127 Then
                indexFirstMask = 10
            End If
            Msg("indexFirstMask: " & indexFirstMask)
            Dim masks As New List(Of Byte)

            Dim x As Integer = indexFirstMask
            While (x < indexFirstMask + 4)
                masks.Add(bytesArray(x))
                x += 1
            End While

            Dim indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
            Dim decoded(byteslen - indexFirstDataByte) As Byte

            Dim i As Integer = 0, j As Integer = 0
            For i = indexFirstDataByte To byteslen Step 1
                Dim mask As Byte = masks(j Mod 4)
                Dim encodedByte As Byte = bytesArray(i)
                decoded(j) = (encodedByte Xor mask)
                j += 1
            Next

            Console.WriteLine("FROM CLIENT: '" & System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded) & "'")
            'Console.WriteLine("temp " + decoded.ToString)
            SendMessage(curSocket, "CONNECTION_OK")
        End If
```