# Reading From a WebSocket in Python (Data from Javascript WebSocket)

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, websocket

I'm having some issues decoding data sent over websockets from Chrome (JavaScript) to a python server (using low-level socket apis). I've handled the handshake properly, the `readyState` of the websocket is OPEN when I use `.send(...)`. I receive byte data (per the specs), but no matter how I try to decode it, it comes out as jibberish or triggers an exception.

javascript

```
var we = new WebSocket(url);
we.send("string data");
```

python

```
data = socket.recv(1024) # socket from sock.accept(...)
#handle data
```

I've tried `data.decode('utf-8')` as that seems like it would be the obvious solution (throws an error). I've tried stripping `\x80` and `\x81` (I think - I read it somewhere on StackOverflow), but it still throws an error...

I've tried base64 decoding - which I found in an answer here on SO (but that doesn't make sense so...)

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you receive after the handshake? It might be compressed.

Comment: @Blender it's garbage in UTF8, but I did a hex dump which comes out to 81:85:86:56:99:b4:ee:33:f5:d8:e9 for the sent string "hello"

Comment: @Blender as far as I'm concerned, it's not using compression as I decline that extension in my handshake response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not versed in WebSocket communication, but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125509/66349), the data is encoded (see the part on Receiving Messages)

```
>>> pkt = [int(x, 16) for x in '81:85:86:56:99:b4:ee:33:f5:d8:e9'.split(':')]
>>> pkt[0] # header should be 129 for text mode
129
>>> len = pkt[1] & 0b01111111
>>> len
5
>>> mask = pkt[2:6]
>>> data = pkt[6:]
>>> for i,c in enumerate(data):
...     print chr(c ^ mask[i % 4])
...
h
e
l
l
o
```

Note, this is just an example of decoding your specific example data and does not take the full spec into account. For instance, the data length can be multiple bytes (so the position of the mask and data block may vary).

Comment: thanks. I don't need the full spec, just niche functionality. I'll give it a try (tonight... maybe - tomorrow I'll return and accept if it worked)

Comment: awesome. it worked. thank you for that post, as well, very helpful.