# Websocket invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, header

I am sending data from a java server to a `javascript` client via a `websocket` in the following manner:

```
private byte[] makeFrame(String message) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteStream.write(0x81);
    byteStream.write(bytes.length);
    byteStream.write(bytes);
    byteStream.flush();
    byteStream.close();
    byte[] data = byteStream.toByteArray();
}
```

But i am getting the error

```
Websocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Invalid frame header
```

when the size is large (i believe above 128 bytes). I am unsure whether this is an issue with the op-code or something else.

Many thanks, Ben

Comment: How long are the message you are trying to send? If it's larger than 125 bytes you need to encode the length in a different manner i.e you must take the extended payload length into consideration.

Comment: Right, of course, so i need to use the next two (or eight) bytes to store the length instead?

Comment: If the length is between 15 and 65535 bytes then your will have to add a two byte extended length, while if it's larger than 65535 bytes than you'll need a 4 byte extended length.

Comment: Checkout http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455, you also have an example here on how to encode your header based on the payload size (this is an php example) https://github.com/CycloneCode/WSServer/blob/master/src/WSServer.php

Comment: Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side

Comment: Awesome, thanks that helps a lot. (i think you meant 125 not 15 in your second comment)

Comment: Haha, yes i did, sorry still a little bit tired =)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here:

```
byteStream.write(bytes.length);
```

There are different schemas, how to encode integer into the byte array. Please [see Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) wikipedia article.

You have to do something by this (this code fragment is [from .Net WebSocket client](https://github.com/deniszykov/WebSocketListener/blob/master/vtortola.WebSockets.Rfc6455/Header/WebSocketFrameHeader.cs#L100)):

```
var arrayLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.length)

if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(arrayLengthBytes, 0, arrayLengthBytes.Length);
}

byteStream.write(arrayLengthBytes);
```