# Javascript - parseInt returns strange values for WebSocket data

Tags: javascript, websocket, parseint

I'm getting some strange behaviour when using the parseInt().

```
webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var raw = event.data;
    alert(raw);
    var data = raw.split(":");

    alert("lat:\"" + data[0] + "\" lon:\"" + data[1] + "\"");

    var x = parseInt(data[0]);
    var y = parseInt(data[1]);

    alert("lat:" + x + " lon:" + y);
}
```

The first alert outputs: 100:100   - this is the string sent from the server.

The second alert outputs: lat:"100" lon:"100" - which is fine

However, the third alert outputs: lat:1 lon:NaN

What could cause this?

**UPDATE:**

The problem was the encoding on the server side generating some invisible unwanted characters. I updated the server code and the problem was gone. [Working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442080/2667737).

Comment: I'm curious to find out... Is going to be something so stupid we are not even thinking about :D

Comment: Might be some characters like space, tabs that cannot be seen in the second data

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/oh9zygao/

Comment: What happens if you do this: `var x = parseInt(data[0]) || 0;` ?

Comment: And what's your browser? :)

Comment: And what if you do this: `parseInt(data[0].trim())` ?

Comment: @Mr.Web parseInt(data[0]) || 0; gives me 1 like before, but parseInt(data[1]) || 0; gives me 0. Tried with trim(), but same result..

Comment: @unixarmy Android default web browser. Same with Chrome for Android.

Comment: Ok, What if you do `window.parseInt(..)`?

Comment: I found the problem. It was on the server side... Thanks for all replies!
Working code (comment #2): http://stackoverflow.com/a/27442080/2667737

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, there are non-printable characters like spaces, tabs, etc. in your data that's why you're getting `NaN` after split.

You can use `regex` to get the data as follow. Using this way, you don't have to worry about non-printable characters as only digits are selected by `regex`.

```js
var raw = '100:100 ';

var data = raw.match(/\d+/g);

var x = parseInt(data[0], 10);
var y = parseInt(data[1], 10);

document.write('x=' + x + '   y=' + y);
```

The above `regex` will select all the digits from `raw` string.

Comment: This gives me an array of single digits. 

data[0] = 1

data[1] = 0

data[2] = 0

data[3] = 1

data[4] = 0

data[5] = 0

Comment: @user2667737 Check the Demo in the answer. Please add the data that you're getting in `raw` in the questin

Comment: That seems to work, but not with `event.data`.. It gives: "x=1 y=0". But I think you have a point, there seems to be invisible characters. `event.data.length` returns 14, while the printed output is only 7 characters..

Comment: 14 chars? Than you are to trim the `raw` variable: `raw.trim()`. Can you provide the full url where you get the 2 data from?

Comment: The server is currently running local. I suspect something is wrong on that side. Here's the code used for sending the string from the server (written in c#): http://pastebin.com/Ti48xTrJ Based on the code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471677/2667737

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tushar. Thus, belive some special characters are being parsed in the `raw = even.data;` (can't replicate here, although)

The code below seems to work fine, you might adjust to yours and test it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var raw = '100 :100asd';
    var data = raw.match(/[0-9]+/gm);

    alert(raw); // console.log(raw);
    var data = raw.split(":");

    alert("lat:\"" + data[0] + "\" lon:\"" + data[1] + "\"");

    var x = parseInt(data[0]);
    var y = parseInt(data[1]);

    alert("lat:" + x + " lon:" + y);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I cannot get that working with `raw = event.data`.. I now tried to access the webpage from a computer, and `alert(event.data)` gave me "1 0 0 : 1 0 0 " (For some reason the Android browser does not output the "spaces", nor does `document.write`). That explains why the length is 14 - there is something between each digit. I tried to replace all spaces with `raw.replace(/ /g, '');`, but the spaces are still there meaning that they probably are something else.

Comment: @user2667737 I see. You could still try this replace as `raw.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')`
Since I'm pretty sure thera are some unicode in between the response :)

And just to clarify:
the caret (^) is the negation of the set [...], gi say global and case-insensitive and the safelist in this example is digits, word characters, underscores (\w) and whitespace (\s).