# Python encode web socket frames

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

i am trying to make a web socket connection between a javascript client and a python server. I have managed to get the handshaking right, and i can send data from the javascript client, and decode it on the server.

The problem appears when i want to send data from the server. When i try to send clear ascii text i get this error on the client `Websocket Error: [object Event]`. Naturally, so i want to "encode" the data before i send it. I have tried a lot of things, including basic base64. But nothing works. I stumbled upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side). Where it is an example of how to prepare data for sending.

Here is the code i've come up with so far:

```
def encodeFrame(bytesRaw):
bytesFormatted = []
bytesFormatted.append(129)

indexStartRawData = 0

if len(bytesRaw) <= 125:
    bytesFormatted.append(len(bytesRaw))

    indexStartRawData = 2

elif len(bytesRaw) >= 126 and len(bytesRaw) <= 65535:
    bytesFormatted.append(126)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 8 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) ) + 255)

    indexStartRawData = 4

else:
    bytesFormatted.append(127)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 56 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 48 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 40 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 32 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 24 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 16 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) >> 8 ) + 255)
    bytesFormatted.append(( len(bytesRaw) ) + 255)

    indexStartRawData = 10

bytesFormatted.put(bytesRaw, indexStartRawData)

return bytesFormatted
```

I think most of it works right, but i have no idea what i should do with the last command: `bytesFormatted.put(bytesRaw, indexStartRawData)`. I've tried just appending to the array, and using the buffer-format. But it won't work. The function which sends the data `client.send(encodeFrame("test"))` in my case, only takes a buffer or string.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this "encoding"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following these `( len(bytesRaw) >> 32 ) + 255` lines.
For instance, if your payload length is 70'000, `else` clause will be executed, giving you a sequence of

```
[127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 256, 528, 70255]
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. Actually, the link you provided proposes to use [*binary AND*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation while you use *arithmetic +* (you may use + if you're to perform binary OR on numbers with non-overlapping 1's in binary form, but not for doing AND). These are very different operations!

Although you may use `( len(bytesRaw) >> 32 ) & 255` it won't guarantee the number will be a single byte long - it's up to interpreter to decide how to store it. In order to overcome this, `struct` module in python is used for assembling binary data. For example, the whole `else` clause collapses to `struct.pack('B', 127) + struct.pack('!Q', len(bytesRaw))`. `!` means network byte order (big-endian), `Q` means 8 byte unsigned integer, `B` means unsigned byte.

Even if you don't want to rewrite the code with `struct` (I don't insist of course), currently you return a `list` from `encodeFrame` function. You can't send a list over a network. You can send C array, but Python list is a very complex object and can't be sent this way. You need to convert it to a byte sequence first:

```
def list_to_bytes(lst):
    format = 'B' * len(lst)
    return struct.pack(format, *lst)
```

---

Also, please don't forget that your payload should be a valid UTF-8 string since you use TEXT frames. Refer to [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for details.