# Sending / receiving WebSocket message over Python socket / WebSocket Client

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, protocols, decode

I wrote a simple WebSocket client. I used the code I found on SO, here: [How can I send and receive WebSocket messages on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side).

I'm using `Python 2.7` and my server is `echo.websocket.org` on `80` TCP port. Basically, I think that I have a problem with receiving messages. (Or maybe the sending is wrong too?)

At least I am sure that the  handshake is all ok, since I receive a good handshake response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 21:54:31 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Upgrade: websocket
```

And my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

def encode_text_msg_websocket(data):
    bytesFormatted = []
    bytesFormatted.append(129)

    bytesRaw = data.encode()
    bytesLength = len(bytesRaw)

    if bytesLength <= 125:
        bytesFormatted.append(bytesLength)
    elif 126 <= bytesLength <= 65535:
        bytesFormatted.append(126)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 8) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(bytesLength & 255)
    else:
        bytesFormatted.append(127)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 56) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 48) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 40) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 32) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 24) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 16) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append((bytesLength >> 8) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(bytesLength & 255)

    bytesFormatted = bytes(bytesFormatted)
    bytesFormatted = bytesFormatted + bytesRaw
    return bytesFormatted


def dencode_text_msg_websocket(stringStreamIn):
    byteArray = [ord(character) for character in stringStreamIn]
    datalength = byteArray[1] & 127
    indexFirstMask = 2
    if datalength == 126:
        indexFirstMask = 4
    elif datalength == 127:
        indexFirstMask = 10
    masks = [m for m in byteArray[indexFirstMask: indexFirstMask + 4]]
    indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
    decodedChars = []
    i = indexFirstDataByte
    j = 0
    while i < len(byteArray):
        decodedChars.append(chr(byteArray[i] ^ masks[j % 4]))
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return ''.join(decodedChars)

# connect 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((socket.gethostbyname('echo.websocket.org'), 80))

# handshake
handshake = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: gfhjgfhjfj\r\nOrigin: http://example.com\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: echo\r\n' \
        'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n'
sock.send(handshake)
print sock.recv(1024)

# send test msg
msg = encode_text_msg_websocket('hello world!')
sock.sendall(msg)

# receive it back
response = dencode_text_msg_websocket(sock.recv(1024))
print '--%s--' % response

sock.close()
```

What is wrong here? It gets complicated after the handshake.

The `dencode_text_msg_websocket` method returns an empty string but it should return the same string I send to the server, which is `hello world!`.

I DO NOT WANT to use libraries (I know how to use them). The question is about achieving the same thing WITHOUT libraries, using only sockets.

I only want to send a message to `echo.websocket.org server` and receive a response, that's all. I do not want to modify the headers, just build the headers like they're used by this server. I checked how they should look like using Wireshark, and tried to build the same packets with Python.

**For tests below, I used my browser:**

Not masked data, from server to client:

[image]

Masked data, from client to server:

[image]

Comment: Your socket layers level are **HIGH**, you can't access to all headers for reconfiguration. Choice only TCP or UDP on ready for use socket connection.

Comment: @dsgdfg: I think I did not understand you. I only want to send a message to `echo.websocket.org` server, that's all. I do not want to modify the headers, just build the headers like they're used by this server. I checked how they should look like using Wireshark, and tried to build the same packets with Python. Please see my edit.

Comment: There is one fundamental difference between your code and the code that you based it on, in the decode definition. You do not convert the input `byteArray = stringStreamIn` instead relying on simply converting a single character to get the length. The original code converts the entire input string  `byteArray = [ord(character) for character in stringStreamIn]`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: Even if I change the code to what you've suggested, the last `print` prints an empty string as a response.

Comment: I suspect that it is your data encoding, look at the python code in `websocket-client`. `sudo pip install websocket-client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.1:

You should mask the client frames. (And the server frames is not masked at all.)

- **a client MUST mask all frames that it
  sends to the server** (see Section 5.3 for further details).  (Note
  that masking is done whether or not the WebSocket Protocol is running
  over TLS.)  The server MUST close the connection upon receiving a
  frame that is not masked.  In this case, a server MAY send a Close
  frame with a status code of 1002 (protocol error) as defined in
  Section 7.4.1.  **A server MUST NOT mask any frames that it sends to
  the client.**  A client MUST close a connection if it detects a masked
  frame。

---

This is a working version:

```
import os
import array
import six
import socket
import struct

OPCODE_TEXT = 0x1

try:
    # If wsaccel is available we use compiled routines to mask data.
    from wsaccel.xormask import XorMaskerSimple
    
    def _mask(_m, _d):
        return XorMaskerSimple(_m).process(_d)

except ImportError:
    # wsaccel is not available, we rely on python implementations.
    def _mask(_m, _d):
        for i in range(len(_d)):
            _d[i] ^= _m[i % 4]

        if six.PY3:
            return _d.tobytes()
        else:
            return _d.tostring()


def get_masked(data):
    mask_key = os.urandom(4)
    if data is None:
        data = ""

    bin_mask_key = mask_key
    if isinstance(mask_key, six.text_type):
        bin_mask_key = six.b(mask_key)

    if isinstance(data, six.text_type):
        data = six.b(data)

    _m = array.array("B", bin_mask_key)
    _d = array.array("B", data)
    s = _mask(_m, _d)

    if isinstance(mask_key, six.text_type):
        mask_key = mask_key.encode('utf-8')
    return mask_key + s


def ws_encode(data="", opcode=OPCODE_TEXT, mask=1):
    if opcode == OPCODE_TEXT and isinstance(data, six.text_type):
        data = data.encode('utf-8')

    length = len(data)
    fin, rsv1, rsv2, rsv3, opcode = 1, 0, 0, 0, opcode

    frame_header = chr(fin << 7 | rsv1 << 6 | rsv2 << 5 | rsv3 << 4 | opcode)

    if length < 0x7e:
        frame_header += chr(mask << 7 | length)
        frame_header = six.b(frame_header)
    elif length < 1 << 16:
        frame_header += chr(mask << 7 | 0x7e)
        frame_header = six.b(frame_header)
        frame_header += struct.pack("!H", length)
    else:
        frame_header += chr(mask << 7 | 0x7f)
        frame_header = six.b(frame_header)
        frame_header += struct.pack("!Q", length)

    if not mask:
        return frame_header + data
    return frame_header + get_masked(data)


def ws_decode(data):
    """
    ws frame decode.
    :param data:
    :return:
    """
    _data = [ord(character) for character in data]
    length = _data[1] & 127
    index = 2
    if length < 126:
        index = 2
    if length == 126:
        index = 4
    elif length == 127:
        index = 10
    return array.array('B', _data[index:]).tostring()


# connect
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((socket.gethostbyname('echo.websocket.org'), 80))

# handshake
handshake = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: ' \
            'Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: gfhjgfhjfj\r\nOrigin: http://example.com\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: ' \
            'echo\r\n' \
            'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n'

sock.send(handshake)
print(sock.recv(1024))

sock.sendall(ws_encode(data='Hello, China!', opcode=OPCODE_TEXT))

# receive it back
response = ws_decode(sock.recv(1024))
print('--%s--' % response)

sock.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now. However, I do not understand some code part. Will you be able to help? This: `frame_header = chr(fin << 7 | rsv1 << 6 | rsv2 << 5 | rsv3 << 4 | opcode)` and this: `chr(mask << 7 | length)`, etc. What do they do?

Comment: @yak See 5.2.  Base Framing Protocol in the link I provided

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: I know how they should look like. The problem is, I do not understand the code.

Answer (score 3):

I have hacked your code into something that at least sends a reply and receives an answer, by changing the encoding to use `chr()` to insert byte strings rather than decimals to the header. The decoding I have left alone but the other answer here has a solution for that.
The real guts of this is detailed here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.txt
which details exactly what it is that you have to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
def encode_text_msg_websocket(data):
    bytesFormatted = []
    bytesFormatted.append(chr(129))
    bytesRaw = data.encode()
    bytesLength = len(bytesRaw)
    if bytesLength <= 125:
        bytesFormatted.append(chr(bytesLength))
    elif 126 <= bytesLength <= 65535:
        bytesFormatted.append(chr(126))
        bytesFormatted.append((chr(bytesLength >> 8)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr(bytesLength) & 255)
    else:
        bytesFormatted.append(chr(127))
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 56)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 48)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 40)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 32)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 24)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 16)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr((bytesLength >> 8)) & 255)
        bytesFormatted.append(chr(bytesLength) & 255)
    send_str = ""
    for i in bytesFormatted:
        send_str+=i
    send_str += bytesRaw
    return send_str

# connect 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(5.0)
try:
    sock.connect((socket.gethostbyname('ws.websocket.org'), 80))
except:
    print "Connection failed"
handshake = '\
GET /echo HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Host: echo.websocket.org\r\n\
Upgrade: websocket\r\n\
Connection: Upgrade\r\n\
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==\r\n\
Origin: http://example.com\r\n\
WebSocket-Protocol: echo\r\n\
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n\
'
sock.send(bytes(handshake))
data = sock.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8')
print data

# send test msg
msg = encode_text_msg_websocket('Now is the winter of our discontent, made glorious Summer by this son of York')
print "Sent: ",repr(msg)
sock.sendall(bytes(msg))
# receive it back
response = sock.recv(1024)
#decode not sorted so ignore the first 2 bytes
print "\nReceived: ", response[2:].decode()
sock.close()
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Mon, 08 May 2017 15:08:33 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Upgrade: websocket


Sent:  '\x81MNow is the winter of our discontent, made glorious Summer by this son of York'

Received:  Now is the winter of our discontent, made glorious Summer by this son of York
```

I should note here, that this is going to be a pig to code without pulling in some extra libraries, as @gushitong has done.