# Java Server, html client, unable to send messages to server

Tags: javascript, java, server, client

i got a little problem with my project. I have a Server written in Java and some clients written in html/js. Connecting works somehow, but as soon as i want to send a message from the client to the server it returns an error: "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state"

Hopefully some of you awesome guys can look over my code and help me :)

Server Code:

Server.java

```
public class Server {

static ArrayList<Clients> clientsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static int clientCount = 1;
private static int port;
private static ServerSocket ss;
private Socket socket;
private Clients clienthandler;
static boolean isRunning = true;

public Server(int port) throws IOException {

    this.port = port;
    setSs(new ServerSocket(port));
}

public void run() throws IOException {

    while (isRunning) {

        log("Listening on " + port + "...");
        socket = getSs().accept();
        log("Receiving client... " + socket);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));        
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            log(s);
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        log("Creating a new handler for this client...");

        clienthandler = new Clients(socket, "Client " + clientCount, in, out);
        Thread t = new Thread(clienthandler);

        clientsArrayList.add(clienthandler);
        log("Added to client list");
        t.start();
        clientCount++;

        GUI.texttoclientlog();
    }

}

public static ServerSocket getSs() {
    return ss;
}

public static void setSs(ServerSocket ss) {
    Server.ss = ss;
}

public void log(String logtext) {
    System.out.println(logtext);
    GUI.texttolog(logtext);

}
```

}

Clients.java

```
public class Clients implements Runnable {

private String name;
final BufferedReader in;
final PrintWriter out;
Socket socket;
boolean isloggedin;

public Clients(Socket socket, String name, BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {

    this.out = out;
    this.in = in;
    this.name = name;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.isloggedin = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    String received;
    while (true) {
        try {
            // receive the string
            received = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(received);

            GUI.messagehandler(this.getName() + ": " + received);

            if (received.equals("logout")) {
                this.isloggedin = false;
                this.socket.close();
                break;
            }

            this.in.close();
            this.out.close();
            this.out.flush();
            this.out.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;

}
```

}

And the JS client code:

```
    <script>
  var connection;

  connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6788/");
  console.log("connection established");

  connection.onmessage = function (e) { console.log(e.data); };
  connection.onopen = () => conn.send("Connection established");
  connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log("WebSocket Error" + error);
  };

  function Send() {
    if (connection.readyState === 1) {
      connection.send("test");
    }
        console.log("error sending");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: where does `conn` come from? i guess it should be `connection.onopen = () => connection.send("Connection established");` instead

Comment: yep, that was wrong too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebSocket session is established via a [handshake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#The_WebSocket_Handshake).
Post the handshake is complete and the connection is upgraded, the server and client can send messages. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java) is a sample WebSocket server in Java.

Update the clients run method to

```
public void run() {

    int len = 0;            
    byte[] b = new byte[80];
    while(true){
        try {
            len = in.read(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(len!=-1){

            byte rLength = 0;
            int rMaskIndex = 2;
            int rDataStart = 0;
            //b[0] is always text in my case so no need to check;
            byte data = b[1];
            byte op = (byte) 127;
            rLength = (byte) (data & op);

            if(rLength==(byte)126) rMaskIndex=4;
            if(rLength==(byte)127) rMaskIndex=10;

            byte[] masks = new byte[4];

            int j=0;
            int i=0;
            for(i=rMaskIndex;i<(rMaskIndex+4);i++){
                masks[j] = b[i];
                j++;
            }

            rDataStart = rMaskIndex + 4;

            int messLen = len - rDataStart;

            byte[] message = new byte[messLen];

            for(i=rDataStart, j=0; i<len; i++, j++){
                message[j] = (byte) (b[i] ^ masks[j % 4]);
            }

            System.out.println(new String(message)); 

            b = new byte[80];

        }
    }
}
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side) SO answer

In my opinion you can leverage the Spring WebSocket support, rather than writing your own. I had created [one](https://github.com/Girija-Shankar-Swain/websocket-protobuf-example) which also uses ProtoBuf or you can look at the Spring WebSocket getting started guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: Nice thanks. It works now. It receives the messages in bytes. but i dont get the decoder part. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the updated code. it receives the bytes from the html clients. but i have no clue how to decode them :)

Server.java

```
public class Server {

static ArrayList<Clients> clientsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static int clientCount = 1;
private static int port;
private static ServerSocket ss;
private Socket socket;
private Clients clienthandler;
static boolean isRunning = true;
private InputStream in;
private OutputStream out;

public Server(int port) throws IOException {

    Server.port = port;
    setSs(new ServerSocket(port));
}

public void run() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    while (isRunning) {

        log("Listening on " + port + "...");
        socket = getSs().accept();
        log("Receiving client... " + socket);

        in = socket.getInputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();


        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        String data = new Scanner(in, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();

        Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);

        if (get.find()) {

            Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
            match.find();
            byte[] response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                    + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                    + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
                            .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11").getBytes("UTF-8")))
                    + "\r\n\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8");

            out.write(response, 0, response.length);

            log("Creating a new handler for this client...");

            clienthandler = new Clients(socket, "Client " + clientCount, in, out);
            Thread t = new Thread(clienthandler);

            clientsArrayList.add(clienthandler);
            log("Added to client list");
            t.start();
            clientCount++;

            GUI.texttoclientlog();

        } else {

            log("Handshake failed");

        }

    }

}

public static ServerSocket getSs() {
    return ss;
}

public static void setSs(ServerSocket ss) {
    Server.ss = ss;
}

public void log(String logtext) {
    System.out.println(logtext);
    GUI.texttolog(logtext);

}
```

}

Clients.java

```
public class Clients implements Runnable {

private String name;
final InputStream in;
final OutputStream out;
Socket socket;
boolean isloggedin;

public Clients(Socket socket, String name, InputStream in, OutputStream out) {

    this.out = out;
    this.in = in;
    this.name = name;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.isloggedin = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    int received;
    while (true) {
        try {

            received = in.read();


            //how to decode??
            System.out.println(received);

            GUI.messagehandler(this.getName() + ": " + received);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;

}
```

}

Comment: How are you running your server?

Comment: i just start it and it receives the bytes "129 150 188 10 108 10 255 101 2 100 217 105 24 99 211 100 76 111 207 126 13 104 208 99 31 98 217 110" from the client for "Connection established".  but i dont know how to decode the message

Comment: I have updated my answer with the client run method.