# How to see Binary data from WebSocket (protocol buffer)

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools, protocol-buffers, binary-data

Is possible to "decompile" the binary data received from some websocket using protocol buffers.

When I go to Chrome Developer Tools > Network I can see the some data sent and received in JSON but the Binary data is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch messages server sent in  "Network" tab at google chrome dev tools. Or you can watch traffic using WireShark. Then decompile data by algorithm([here is a good description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side))