# TcpListener and WebSocket failds: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

Using TcpListener in C# as my server and WebSocket in JavaScript as my client I established a connection and performed an handshake properly, I can receive as much data as I want from my client but I cant seem to send data out, I get the following error on every attempt I make:

> One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0,
>   reserved3 = 0

Perhaps I need to encode data coming out from my server as part of the WebSocket protocol?

How can one approach this correctly?

Comment: Pheraps this may be related? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442080/8329804)

Comment: See : https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/823