# Websocket : Problem Server send to Client

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket, tcp

I'm new to Websockets and looking for working samples WS C# console application. I ran into this one (Follow Link) but I already have a problem. When the client sends a message to the server, the server can read it but he cannot send it to client.

[LinkWebSocketServer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

```
public static void Main() {
    string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 80;
    var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

    server.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection...", ip, port);

    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // enter to an infinite cycle to be able to handle every change in stream
    while (true) {
        while (!stream.DataAvailable);
        while (client.Available < 3); // match against "get"

        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
        string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
            Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

            // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
            // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
            // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
            // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
            string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
            string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
            string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

            // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
            byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

            stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
        } else {
            bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"

            int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                msglen = bytes[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
                offset = 2;

            if (msglen == 126) {
                // was ToUInt16(bytes, offset) but the result is incorrect
                msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                offset = 4;
            } else if (msglen == 127) {
                Console.WriteLine("TODO: msglen == 127, needs qword to store msglen");
                // i don't really know the byte order, please edit this
                // msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6] }, 0);
                // offset = 10;
            }

            if (msglen == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
            else if (mask) {
                byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                offset += 4;

                for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                    decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
            } else
                Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [console application output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvADN.png)
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Were does javascript comes in? Is this tag correct?

Comment: Today I fixed  the error of sending data server c# to js client  with this link  ! i found method of sending data ( C# "EncodeMessageToSend(String message) "). then i added in last line  of  ("else if (mask){}" ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side